# Having trouble with proliferating disk partitions

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I have a couple of questions about my disk partitions. Here is my current setup:

[image]

1. I just bought and installed *Disk 1 (Samsung SSD)*. I initialized and formatted the entire drive. So where did the second partition come from? Also, the size does not seem proportional to the actual percent of disk space (536 MB out of 930+ GB).
2. *Disk 2 (SSD)* is the original boot drive that came with the computer and I'd like to dump all those partitions as well. Right clicking on the *SSD (E:)* partition allows me to delete or reformat the volume. But right clicking on any other partition gives me a context menu with only a Help command. Is there any way to combine the partitions on this drive to a single partition?
3. How come the other partitions are not available through File Explorer and the file system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just bought and installed Disk 1 (Samsung SSD). I initialized and formatted the entire drive. So where did the second partition come from? Also, the size does not seem proportional to the actual percent of disk space (536 MB out of 930+ GB).

Windows automatically creates a "recovery" partition by shrinking the main OS partition. Its size is always somewhere between 500M–1G, because it only contains a frozen OS image (a .wim file whose size is known in advance); it won't be accumulating data.

> Disk 2 (SSD) is the original boot drive that came with the computer and I'd like to dump all those partitions as well. Right clicking on the SSD (E:) partition allows me to delete or reformat the volume. But right clicking on any other partition gives me a context menu with only a Help command. Is there any way to combine the partitions on this drive to a single partition?

Use other tools such as `diskpart` to delete the partitions.

```
C:\> diskpart
DISKPART> list disk
DISKPART> select disk X
DISKPART> list partition
```

From there, you can either `clean` the whole disk at once, or you can `sel[ect] part[ition]` and `del part` one by one. For example, if you want to delete partition shown as #3 in "list part":

```
DISKPART> sel part 1
DISKPART> del part override
```

The `override` keyword is useful.

**Warning:** The first partition on this disk is an *EFI System Partition*. When the system boots in UEFI mode, it loads the OS bootloader from this partition – not from the MBR. You need to have this partition *somewhere*, although you should create one on your brand-new SSD instead.

Creating a new ESP can be done from Windows install media (always have an installation USB/CD handy) or from a running OS. There was already a separate thread about how to do this, I'll try to find a link.

> How come the other partitions are not available through File Explorer and the file system?

Partitions are not required to have a drive letter assigned (e.g. you can remove it through the same diskmgmt.msc).

These specific partitions deliberately don't have one, because they're marked as having a specific system purpose, rather than generic data storage – assigning them a drive letter would just clutter File Explorer and increase the risk of someone accidentally deleting e.g. the *.efi bootloader files or the recovery image.

Comment: *Windows automatically creates a "recovery" partition by shrinking the main OS partition* - Can I ask why? Why does a data drive need a recovery partition? Recovery from what?

Comment: *The first partition on this disk is an EFI System Partition. When the system boots in UEFI mode, it loads the OS bootloader from this partition – not from the MBR. You need to have this partition somewhere, although you should create one on your brand-new SSD instead* - I will no longer be booting from this drive. I wish Disk Management was a little more capable.

Comment: It sounds very much like the drive _wasn't_ a data drive when the partition was created -- it was the OS drive at the time.